# Remove leading % from integer

Tags: c++

Just a simple problem here: I have a char** argv[] that holds all of my arguments...in one of these arguments, I get an integer proceeded by a %

For example:

bg %2

I really just want the integer....is there an easy way to get this?

This is for homework, so I am willing to do some more digging if anyone can prod me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: You want `argv[n]+1` (which, to get an `int`, you'll then feed to something like `atoi` or (preferred) `strtol`).

Comment: are you expecting the number to be a single digit all the time or can it be multiple digits? %23657?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/):

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != argc ; i++) {
    if (argv[i][0] == '%') {
        int num = atoi(&argv[i][1]);
        printf("Got a number: %d\n", num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this assuming that the % is at the start of the string which the OP has shown in his example is not always the case? Also will this work with multiple digits?

Comment: @Ben The OP has shown all parameters passed to his program. This means that `argv` will contain `"bg"` and `"%2"` at separate indexes.

Comment: Because the arguments will always be in the same positions, this one allowed me use atoi and to use it for what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it using c++ methods:

lets assume you have one of the `char*` in the list `char** argv[]`

```
std::string tempString(argv[the one with the %]);
int position = tempString.find_first_of('%');
int = atoi(tempString.substr(position, tempString.size()-position).c_str());
```

A quick explination, the first line converst the `char*` into a `std::string`, the second line gets the position of the `%`, the third line gets the sub-string of the number (assuming it ends at the end of the `char*`), converts it back to a `char*` and passes it through `atoi` to get the `int`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: every time i see someone submitting ready-to-use code to a homework problem, i get seriously frustrated. when a person is able to write the code, he or she *should* be intelligent enough to not submit it, but rather explain it. are these persons (e.g. you) just intent on sabotaging other students?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Sorry mate, I didnt mean to personally offend you, I did explain how the answer works as well. Also the code is basicly pseudo code. I get seriously frustrated when people on the internet cant keep there emotions to themselves.

Comment: No worries--I promise that I can write this sort of thing, I'm just new to c++ and was hoping for something like the atoi. I appreciate the help. I know that I can't copy directly and I did not for this.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Looks like the OP was ok with it. I noticed you didn't comment on dasblinkenlight's post. I think you are one of those guys who trolls the site looking for people who are reasonably new and attack there posts to make you feel better about yourself. I bet you are really short.